# Script for merging two SSH connections together?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, debian

I'm trying to write a bash script to merge 2 already-existing SSH connections.

For example, if I have an embedded device automatically creating an SSH connection to my server (from behind a firewall), how can I connect to that server in the middle, and jump into the already-existing connection from that embedded device?

I have looked into the possibility of using the server as a 'jump host', but it seems like I will need to reliably determine (and send SSH requests) to that embedded device?

I have also looked at having the embedded device create a 'screen' on the remote server and connect to that, but that just seems like it would be operating on the remote server.

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this, but I don't know where else to ask.

Comment: I think SSH is kinda designed specifically to *prevent* what you're attempting, which sounds like a one-off of a "man in the middle"  scenario...

Comment: Well, hmm. If that's the case, is there a slightly different way you can propose to solve this problem? Is there some sort of ssh magic I am unaware of that would allow me to connect THROUGH a firewall somehow? I have an embedded device making an outside connection (to my server) but I need to get TO that device somehow, regardless of any firewall / NAT that might stand in the way.

Comment: Hmm...sounds to me like you need some kind of tunnel or uPNP capability. Does something like http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work give any ideas?

Comment: You realize what you just asked for is a way to bypass any firewall and NAT devices (from the outside) that exist between you and a target, right? Which is, in part, exactly what those devices are designed not to allow.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: David - I appreciate the link, that got me started on the right path, that's exactly what I needed to hear. If you wanna throw that as the answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Sorry @MartinPrikryl, can I move it and not copy and paste it?

Comment: Good. if you don't mind, I"ll post that as an answer.

Comment: @DavidW Man, you're fast!! Yeah, I didn't mean to hit 'enter' on that comment so soon, I was just about to tell you to do it :)

Comment: LOL glad I was able to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your requirements are going to need either a uPNP solution or tunnelling solution to get through your firewall. The following link discusses reverse SSH tunneling as one part of this solution.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work